# Does parallelism of cardinal comparison between sets and their power sets, enact a form of choice?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, cardinal-characteristics

Let $ * $ range over cardinal relations $ \{<,<>\}$; if we add the following axiom to $\sf ZF$, would that prove a known form of choice?

**Parallelism:** $  |x|  * |y| \leftrightarrow |\mathcal P(x)|  *  |\mathcal P(y)| $

Where, $<>$ stands for incomparability; that is,  absence of an injection in both directions.

Comment: I don't understand why you have so many relations with the bidirectional implication and universal quantifier. $=$ and $<$ are enough.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, OK, I've edited it. I kept the bidirectional because it's more in spirit with this assertion.

Comment: I didn't say to remove the bidirectional implication, I just said that with it are $=$ and $\neq$ are equivalent (and with the universal quantifier, $<$ and $>$ are equivalent).